# Answer a phone call with a custom record

Tags: java, android

I would like to know if it is possible to answer a phone call in Android with a custom sound recorded on my phone.

I mean, when a phone call is coming, I picked-up the phone and the person who is calling me listen a message I´ve previously recorded on my phone.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: At first, to answer calls you need `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission which is only granted to system apps.

Comment: This has been asked several time before, and the answer is still "No, it's not possible".